# How to play google drive video in jwplayer?

Tags: video, youtube, google-docs, jwplayer

I have been trying fro 2 days to play the googledrive video in jwplayer but no avail. I have watched video tutorials from youtube also tried so many links to do this task but still no success. This is what I am trying.

upload video(mp4) in the folder
make the video and folder public
get the folder id and video name and replace with this link
https://googledrive.com/host/folderid/filename

but it is not working at all.any help?

Comment: Show us a real testable link for faster advice

Comment: @VC.One https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqSR8t2SyvaelRZTUxpVHgxbEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. I've seen now. You may delete your link comment (if you want it private).

Answer (score 2):

Just provide this link as MP4 source :

`http://docs.google.com/uc?id=VIDEO_ID`

The `VIDEO_ID` itself is found in the part of your link as shown below:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/VIDEO_ID/view`

(in your case `VIDEO_ID` begins *"0BxqS"* and ends with *"xbEU"*)

Edit : (make sure you specify `type: "mp4"` so JW Player knows the data type).

```
jwplayer("player").setup ({

file:   "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BzIpsk3FR4R1NjlnTWVDOHB2MTQ",
type:   "mp4",
width:  640,
height: 360, 

});
```

Comment: it is not working

<script>
 jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
     "file": "http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BzIpsk3FR4R1NjlnTWVDOHB2MTQ",
     "image": "http://example.com/myImage.png",
     "height": 360,
     "width": 640
 });
 </script>

Comment: I am waiting for your answer?

Comment: Try the code in edit. Since there is no MP4 extension in the link URL, you must specify `type: "mp4"`. If still not working then remove the `image` line and test. Go to [**this JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/6YyXH/70/) and replace their code in _Javascript_ box with my above shown code and click "Run" to test a working version.

Comment: thanks for your help. It is working fine. Now I have two questions

How to play subtitles from a live link like? https://moviefull-hd.org/subs/bo/2041D.srt
How would I know that the video link of google drive is of type mp4?
If someone share a video link of .avi that how would I know that this link is of the video of type .avi?

Comment: I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @dev What reply are you waiting for? Your question about how can JWPlayer play a video link that has no format extension has been answered correctly (ie: manually specify the format _type_). It's **against site rules to include various topics in one question** since it does not help future readers to find solution for same problem... Consider that _"subtitles from live link"_ has nothing to do with **question Title**. Ask a new question so the right visitor may see and possibly answer. I volunteer knowledge about video/image/sound data only.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use WordPress Plugin and Play With Video.js & JW Player Style (Skin)
2. Shortcodes

Google Drive Video & Poster.

```
[GDPlayer gdrive="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gNAt_8dBiLmvL9fLpSUQZZlh_ViNKA4l/view" poster="https://ingolin.com/example.png"]
```

Google Drive Video, Poster & subtitles

```
[GDPlayer gdrive="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gNAt_8dBiLmvL9fLpSUQZZlh_ViNKA4l/view" poster="https://ingolin.com/example.png"][track kind="captions" src="https://ingolin.com/wp-content/subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default="true"][/GDPlayer]
```

[Demo](https://ingolin.com/gd-player-self-hosting-mp4-google-drive-videos-wordpress-plugin/)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WP0ITSGIfLY)

Answer (score 1):

**New 2022 Solution**: Yes, you can! After a lot of fiddling I got it working. You can input a gdrive url for JW to upload, and even bypassing the virus scan popup.

**How:**

When you want to upload to JW via the API, use “fetch” method as you normally would. This is will be the format for the “download_url”:

Format:
googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/**FILEID**?alt=media&key=**APIKEY**

Example:
googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/**acedkgjasd23hgsad**?alt=media&key=**yusx01plasdpyyyjasudf**

The ?alt=media tells google that you are downloading this file. The API key is required for downloads 100mb+ (to bypass virus scan popup). The API key can be created in your Google Console by creating a new project, enabling google drive API (under API & Services), go to the project credentials and create a new api key.

Comment: which type of API key is required for this? Is it Google Cloud API or Cloud Datastore API or something else?

Comment: i have an existing file, when i fill in fileid and apikey it says the file cannot be found